# Neo4j OGM session object creation policy

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have a web application which exposes api for saving nodes in neo4j.

I am using neo4j OGM.

Every http request should use an existing neo4j session or create a new neo4j session for every request?

Answer (score 1):

In general "drivers" are heavyweight, long-lived objects.   "Sessions" are just wrappers for a set of transactions.  You can [read more here](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/sessions-transactions/)

So the short answer is that there shouldn't be any harm in using a session for each request to keep them isolated, but you should *not* use a driver for each request.   You may want to post more about what your code and language is though.

Comment: Using Java and Neo4j OGM, hence using sessionfactory and session objects. In my jersey web application am using only one sessionfactory object, question is should i use one or every in coming request should create a new session object.